# .net maui 7 Build Android error NETSDK1181: Error getting pack version: Pack ... was not present in workload manifests

Tags: android, maui, .net-7.0

Build Android on .net maui 7.

Help to fix Error NETSDK1181 Error getting pack version: Pack 'Microsoft.Android.Ref.32' was not present in workload manifests

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwh0t.png)

Comment: Could you please post the full error log of this problem?

Comment: This Full Error
Error getting pack version: Pack 'Microsoft.Android.Ref.32' was not present in workload manifests. C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.304\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets

Comment: You can try creating a new app to see if this problem also occurs. But you can try to update your visual studio to the latest version first and try again.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. We have 3 Xamarin Android projects, one is a library that the other two share, so we upgraded that one first. I've changed all the Xamarin NuGet packages to MAUI, updated all the usings statements where needed, but I cannot get it to build on any platform other than .34. Anything else I get the same error. I've installed all the Android SDK's, but nothing works. Still looking for a solution...

Answer (score 1):

I resoled this by changing the proj file to reference android34 like so:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net8.0-ios;net8.0-android34.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

I did get one more error after that change:

```
Error   XA1036  AndroidManifest.xml //uses-sdk/@android:minSdkVersion '21' does not match the $(SupportedOSPlatformVersion) value '29.0' in the project file
```

To resolve that I updated my Androidmanifest.xml file to v29 like this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="29" android:targetSdkVersion="34" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, while opening a .NET MAUI project create on macOS from  a Windows Virtual Machine (via a shared folder between the two platforms).

Solution was for me:

1. Create and a run successfully a new MAUI project inside windows.
2. Move my MAUI project (that has the problem) inside de Virtual Machine (not in the shared folder).
3. Fix any code issue related to Windows platform (missing/wrong `using`...).

*ps Editing csproj as suggested by Visual Studio 2022 wasn't not a solution, comparing my csproj to the one from the blank project reveal that my csproj was identical to the blank one (minus project name)*